# Tricks to make app more efficient on battery consumption.(iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Are there any tricks/methods to optimize the battery usage that you app uses?

I've an app that can play streaming audio in the background quiet well. It does the basics like put the app in the background after a little time of no interfacing with the screen by the user.

Are there any other tricks to be done to stop it eating the battery like a fat man at an all you can eat buffet!

Thanks,
-Code

Comment: We all out of ideas peeps? Seems there is nothing to be done really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrease the usage of the internet and in the case that you are using the Location librairies don't use them except if you need them in which case don't use cutting eye accuracy. The most valid trick for this is no GPS no Geolocation.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Reading in data over a network connection is one of the most power hungry operations on the device. Depending on your protocol, you maybe able to optimize the streaming by buffering larger chunks at a time (if possible). Obviously if this is realtime streaming of a live feed that is not an option.

Review Apple's guidelines here: [Performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Performance/Performance.html), make sure you scroll down to the Reduce Power Consumption section. Basically, to reduce power consumption, you should do as little as possible. If you are turning on frameworks like CoreLocation or using the accelerometers, you should disable those as often as possible. Try releasing as many resources as you possibly can when in the background. Less memory means less overhead for the system to keep track of as well.